# Using SQL datareader to extract 1 to many custom object in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

I'm having issues with the SQL reader class.

I have a custom object named Airport on the database. But im having trouble using the datareader correctly. When i try to extract all Airports into a list(see method 2 below) it seems to jump of the while(_reader.Read()) loop before adding the object to the list.

Any suggestions?

To extract the object do i use 3 methods:

1. To find a specific object:

   ```
   public Airport FindAirportByCode(string _airportCode)
   {
       con.Open();
       string query = "SELECT * from Airport WHERE airportCode = '" + _airportCode + "'";
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
       SqlDataReader _reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       Airport retAirport = BuildAirport(_reader);
       _reader.Close();
       con.Close();
       return retAirport;
   }
   ```
2. To get all Airports into a list

   ```
   public List<Airport> SelectAll()
   {
       con.Open();
       List<Airport> airports = new List<Airport>();
       string query = "SELECT * from Airport";
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

       SqlDataReader _reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       while (_reader.Read())
       {
           Airport temAirport = new Airport();
           temAirport = BuildAirport(_reader);
           airports.Add(temAirport); // It seems to skip this step and only add the last Airport from BuildAirport to the list.
       }

       _reader.Close();
       con.Close();
       return airports;
   }
   ```
3. To build it into an object in C#

   ```
       private Airport BuildAirport(SqlDataReader _reader)
   {

       Airport temAirport = new Airport();
       while (_reader.Read())
       {
           temAirport.airportCode = (string) _reader["airportCode"];
           temAirport.airportName = (string) _reader["airportName"];
           temAirport.country = (string) _reader["country"];
           temAirport.city = (string) _reader["city"];
       }
       _reader.Close();



       return temAirport;
   }
   ```

Comment: your select query with parameter is prone to sql injection attack..Use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In third step you are enumarating `reader` again and that is why you get only one airport when you want to retrieve all of them.

```
private Airport BuildAirport(SqlDataReader _reader)
{

    Airport temAirport = new Airport();
    temAirport.airportCode = (string) _reader["airportCode"];
    temAirport.airportName = (string) _reader["airportName"];
    temAirport.country = (string) _reader["country"];
    temAirport.city = (string) _reader["city"];
    return temAirport;
}
```

And now we have to change your first method because changing `BuildAirport` breaks it. We have to read one row in `FindAirportByCode` now.

```
public Airport FindAirportByCode(string _airportCode)
{
    con.Open();
    string query = "SELECT * from Airport WHERE airportCode = @airportCode";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@airportCode", _airportCode);

    SqlDataReader _reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    Airport retAirport = null;
    if (_reader.Read())
    {
         retAirport = BuildAirport(_reader);
    }

    _reader.Close();
    con.Close();
    return retAirport;
}
```

Use parametrized queries for security.

Comment: Why pass the reader when you could pass only the current row?

Comment: Could you it explain it a little bit mate ?

Comment: @SimonNordahl you were traversing `_reader` in both second and third method. That resulted in only one airport added to list.